# Is mains 220 VAC rms, peak to peak or max amplitude?

Tags: ac

Please excuse me for such a basic question, but I can't seem to find a clear answer to it.

When we say that mains power is 220 VAC, or 230, 110 or whatever value, is that the signal's amplitude, the difference from peak to peak or the RMS value?

Comment: Why ask here when it is so clearly explained at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country  section: Voltages: *All voltages are root mean square voltage; the peak AC voltage is greater by a factor of √2, and the peak-to-peak voltage greater by a factor of 2√2.*

Comment: Thanks for your useful link, Bimpelrekkie. I suppose I've got used to finding answers to my questions in the StackExchange network.

Comment: Then don’t be surprised by the downvotes you get...

Comment: That's fair enough; I didn't come here seeking upvotes, I came seeking knowledge. But I do appreciate what you are trying to tell me. Thanks, Solar Mike :-)

Comment: Honestly not sure why this is downvoted. It's a legit question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we talk about AC voltages, if we don't explicitly state RMS then we imply RMS (unless some other term is used like peak or peak-to-peak).

Answer (score 2):

Unless specified otherwise, AC voltage is RMS; this will make it easier to compare to DC.